# Break constraints and read programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

Создаю свой `dropdown` на **swift** для `ios`. Он получает массив строк и из них формирует выпадающий список. У него есть опорное `UIView`, которое видно всегда, там отображается текущее выбранное значение. Если в массиве строк, переданном Dropdown'y больше одного значения, то в опорном `UIView` есть иконка "стрелка вниз", если значение только одно, то в `UIView` показан только текст, при этом текст размещается по центру опорного `UIView`, а иконка со стрелкой скрывается.

Чаще всего в массиве строк переданном Dropdown'y больше одного значения, поэтому в `.xib` я создал вариант именно для текста с иконкой. Задал следующие `constraints`. Текст и иконка имеют небольшие отступы от родительского view соответственно `leading` и `trailing`. Текст (`UILabel`) растянут на весь родительский `view` и имеет небольшой отступ `trailing`. Текст и иконка имеют `constraint CenterVertically` и у иконки есть `constraints width` и `height`.

Следовательно для варианта когда у дропдауна только одно значение нам надо скрыть иконку, изменить `constraints` у текста и изменить его `alignment`. Свободного места остается много, поэтому уменьшаем ширину дропдауна до 5/8 предыдущей. Для начала пошел самым простым путем, работая с точками:

```
    switch appearance {
    case .Text:
        icon.hidden = true
        let nw = w < (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2) ? (w * 5 / 8) : w
        self.width = nw
        self.x += (w - nw) / 2

        if (type == .Dropdown) {
            label.textAlignment = .Center
            label.center = self.center
        }
```

Желаемого результата не получил. Текст уползает из `view`. Пробовал менять ширину, но безрезультатно, похоже все таки мешали constraints из `.xib`, которые притягивали его за `leading` и trai`l`ing к родительскому `view` (хотя тоже не до конца ясно, потому что ширина родительского view меняется в коде)
вернулся к `constraints`:

```
    switch appearance {
    case .Text:
        icon.hidden = true
        let nw = w < (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2) ? (w * 5 / 8) : w
        self.width = nw
        self.x += (w - nw) / 2
        if (type == .Dropdown) {
            label.textAlignment = .Center

            var cs : [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
            for const in label.constraints {
                cs.append(const)
            }
            label.removeConstraints(cs)

            let cx = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
            let cy = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
            label.width = nw
            self.addConstraint(cx)
            self.addConstraint(cy)
        }
```

В результате текст полностью пропадает из `dropdown`! Предположил что дело в том, что нет `constraints` для `width` и `height` текста

```
    switch appearance {
    case .Text:
        icon.hidden = true
        let nw = w < (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2) ? (w * 5 / 8) : w
        self.width = nw
        self.x += (w - nw) / 2
        if (type == .Dropdown) {


            label.textAlignment = .Center

            var cs : [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
            for const in label.constraints {
                cs.append(const)
            }
            label.removeConstraints(cs)

            let cx = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)
            let cy = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)

            // 6 просто потому что 6 )) чтобы убедиться что оно работает
            let cw = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 6)
            let ch = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 6)
            label.width = nw
            self.addConstraint(cx)
            self.addConstraint(cy)
            label.addConstraint(cw)
            label.addConstraint(ch)
        }
```

В каком направлении можно двинуться для достижения желаемого результата?

Comment: Из самого легкого - расставьте все необходимые constraints в interface builder и затем меняйте в коде их значения

Comment: а можно как то убрать из вопроса все не относящееся непосредственно к проблеме? типа вот надпись с картинкой работает, надпись без картинки не работает

Comment: тогда будут советы задать все в .xib, а у меня либо для одного режима работы .xib либо для другого

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую.

1. Из написанного не очень понятно как привязан Label с текстом слева к родительскому View. Если не задать Leading или Width constraint, то будет убегать.
2. Для изменения constraint лучше всего использовать следующий подход:

   - Создать свойство для NSLayoutConstraint
   - Привязать соответствующий элемент constraint из xib/storyboard
   - В коде менять например следующим образом

     ```
     self.textLabelLeadingConstraint.constant = 0;
     self.textLabelLeadingConstraint.multiplier = 1;
     ```
   - Отправить на перерисовку

     ```
     self.textLabel.setNeedsLayout();
     ```